# How to Check username already exists in the database or not and validate the username without spaces

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a register form that can check whether there is or not in the database and how to validate the username must use alphanumeric and no spaces, 
this is my code for now

```
String validateUsername(String value) {
 String pattern = r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
if (value.length == 0) {
  return "Username is Required";
} else if(!regExp.hasMatch(value)){
  return "Invalid username";
}else {
  return null;
}
```

}

I think the validation is almost the same as email, but I'm still confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it.
while using flutter.

```
// import needed for BlackListingTextInputFormatter function
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; 

TextField(
     inputFormatters: [
          BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(
            new RegExp("[^a-z^A-Z^0-9]+")) //Regex for accepting only alphanumeric characters
          ],
)
```

using this it will ensure no character other than alphanumeric can pass through the textfield.

so now you just need to check the string you get from that field with the database.

You can make an api and make an query like

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = "userName";
```

if you get an empty response then that username is available.

Comment: so when the username input has a space, can't?.. I mean there are no space characters in alphanumeric?

Comment: can new RegExp `("[^a-z^A-Z^0-9]+"))`be entered into my class validateUsername?

Comment: your textField will allow users to only enter alphanumeric characters other than that no character can be used in the textField

Comment: thank youu @VickySalunkhe... but what if the validation for the website format?

Comment: according to me no need to validate once again on backend side as backend will get the data from front end only, and we are validating the data on the front end right? if this answer helped you please do mark it as useful